# Facing Job backpressure issue with Flink S3 sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am doing minute level partitioning of data with Flink S3 sink. I am noticing spike in job backpressure duration due to this minute level partioning. Is there any Flink s3 configs which we can tune to improve this performance. With Kinesis sink, we did increase the queue limit of kinesis sink in past to fix backpressure issue there. Is there any similar queue/buffer size configs with S3 sink which we can tune?

```
StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat(
                s3SinkPath,
                new ParquetWriterFactory<>(builder))
                .withBucketAssigner(new CustomDateTimeBucketAssigner())
                .withBucketCheckInterval(60000)
                .build();
```

Comment: Another options is that if your Task Managers are not bandwidth limited by the hosts where they are running, you can try increasing the parallelism of the sink, so it parallelizes S3 uploads. Take into account that a lot of times not having the same parallelism in all operators reduces the overall job throughput (due to shuffling across operators).

Comment: @GerardGarcia If I increase the operator parallelism, I am seeing lot of s3 throttling, though we have retry mechanism in place but still dont want to land into more backpressure state due to multiple retries

Comment: Can you try this out with the FileSink instead of the StreamingFileSink? The FileSink is the target interface for file sink, the StreamingFileSink will be deprecated soon.

Comment: @MartijnVisser, Thanks for this input. I am trying to use the same

Comment: Just updated StreamingFileSink to FileSink. Hope there is no other change required

FileSink.forBulkFormat(s3SinkPath, new ParquetWriterFactory<>(builder))
                .withRollingPolicy(new CustomCheckpointFileRollingPolicy(fileRollingInterval))
                .withBucketAssigner(new CustomDateTimeBucketAssigner())
                .build()

Comment: What about increasing `fs.s3.maxConnections`? At least on EMR this was necessary to avoid S3 being the bottleneck for our workflows.

Comment: @kkrugler I can see some improvement post setting the max-connections to 150. Is there any max limit on what can we set on this?

Comment: We used `4096` successfully in our workflow.